# better approach to copy portion of char array than strncpy

Tags: c++, char, strncpy

I used `std::strncpy` in [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) to copy portion of a char array to another char array. It seems that it requires to manually add the ending character `'\0'`, in order to properly terminate the string.

As below, if not explicitly appending `'\0'` to `num1`, the char array may have other characters in the later portion.

```
  char buffer[] = "tag1=123456789!!!tag2=111222333!!!10=240";
  char num1[10];
  std::strncpy(num1, buffer+5, 9);  
  num1[9] = '\0';
```

Is there better approach than this? I'd like to have a one-step operation to reach this goal.

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: `string.substr` would help you.

Comment: tbh that was possible in c++98 too.. I still write on it at work

Comment: *"I'd like to have a one-step operation to reach this goal"* Then write a function that achieves your goal, and call that.

Comment: @Swift: Better than the C++87 they still use in India ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit wait.. C++ appeared in 90-91... ah, scratch that , Wiki says 1985. Strange enough I never saw a PC C++ compiler before Symantec\Borland ones..

Comment: @Swift They use a DOS emulator, if that clears things up any

Comment: I'm not even horrified by that, just mortified by stubbornness. Borland C++ 2.1 (first that was "C++") was DOS only and it was 1992-sh for me... pretty much until 1995 most things were DOS or DOS -compatible :P Yes, I'm that old.

Comment: @Swift: Pfft, that's not old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, working with "strings" in C was rather verbose, wasn't it!

Fortunately, C++ is not so limited:

```
const char* in = "tag1=123456789!!!tag2=111222333!!!10=240";
std::string num1{in+5, in+15};
```

If you can't use a `std::string`, or don't want to, then simply wrap the logic you have described into a *function*, and call that function.

---

> As below, if not explicitly appending '\0' to num1, the char array may have other characters in the later portion.

Not quite correct. There is no "later portion". The "later portion" you thought you observed was other parts of memory that you had no right to view. By failing to null-terminate your would-be C-string, your program has *undefined behaviour* and the computer could have done anything, like travelling back in time and murdering my great-great-grandmother. Thanks a lot, pal!

It's worth noting, then, that because it's C library functions doing that out-of-bounds memory access, if you hadn't used those library functions in that way then you didn't *need* to null-terminate `num1`. Only if you want to treat it as a C-style string later is that required. If you just consider it to be an array of 10 bytes, then everything is still fine.

Comment: `Not quite correct.` I think OP means the  "later portion" of the initial string, as they try to extract first sequence of numbers

Comment: @KillzoneKid: That isn't my interpretation. Doesn't really matter either way, of course!